# Text document to dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, text, dictionary, document

Okay, I have a text file that "relationships.txt" that has the following inside:

```
Elizabeth: Peter, Angela, Thomas
Mary: Tom
Angela: Fred, Alison
Alison: Beatrice, Dick, Harry

mother Elizabeth
mother Tom
mother Angela
mother Gurgle
```

The first 4 lines are set up as Mother: Child, Child, Child etc
The bottom 4 lines are statements that should return a result. Eg:

`mother Elizabeth` should return: `Mother not known`

while

`mother Tom` should return: `Mary`

I am meant to create a dictionary to allow this to work, but I have no clue what to do. Help is appreciated.

So far I have the following:

```
test_file = open('relationships.txt', 'w')
test_file.write('''Elizabeth: Peter, Angela, Thomas
Mary: Tom
Angela: Fred, Alison
Alison: Beatrice, Dick, Harry

mother Elizabeth
mother Tom
mother Angela
mother Gurgle
''')
test_file.close()

def create_list():
    open_file = open('relationships.txt', 'r')
    lines = open_file.readlines()
    return(lines)
```

Comment: Absolutely no idea at all? You haven't tried anything whatsoever?

Comment: this is probably a good place to start: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: People are not going to do your problem for you.  You need to post code and then people will help you with what you don't understand or what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: I do have some idea what I need to do. I need to read the entire file into a list of lines. I could then find the blank line that separates the two parts of the file and pass one sub-list of lines to a function that returns a dictionary mapping child names to their mothers and the other sub-list to a function that processes a list of queries. But just a bit unsure how to do this :S

Comment: I do understand, I will post what I have done so far in a minute

Comment: added what I have so far.

Comment: @user2383844 What purpose does `mother Elizabeth` etc. serve? Does that have to be in that file, or are you actually looking for a function that'll find and print it out for you?

Comment: okay so basically it has to be in the file. It has to be recognized and return the correct result for whatever mother xxx is in the file.

Comment: @user2383844 Ok. It's doable. Should the result be printed out to a terminal?

Comment: So in other words, the file may change and have different mother xxx statements in it, but this script should return the correct result for whatever mother xxx statements are in it.

Comment: @timss yes. it should be

Comment: @user2383844 For the fun/practice of it I'll try to hack something together. Altough I do agree with monkut etc.; SO generally isn't for requesting code to be written for you, but to answer questions and solve problems.

Comment: @timss I completely understand, and I feel bad for doing this, I just dont really know what to do. Even if you just got me started I would be greatful :)

Comment: greatful? lol! This question smells like homework...

Comment: @timss how would I go about starting this?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to finish, it's late, but this should get you going, binding children to their mothers with a list of tuples.
It's kinda hacky, but the structure of your file is rather weird (and I still don't see why you would have to use something like that).

```
import re

rel = {}

with open("test/relationships.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Valid Mother: Child, Child, [..]
        try:
            # Remove newliens and spaces
            line = re.sub('[\n ]', '', line)
            mother = line.split(':')[0]
            children = line.split(':')[1].split(',')

            # Append a tuple (child, mother)
            for c in children:
                rel.append((c, mother))

        # Something else, ignore for now
        except:
            continue

print rel
```

Gives:

`[('Peter', 'Elizabeth'), ('Angela', 'Elizabeth'), ('Thomas', 'Elizabeth'), ('Tom', 'Mary'), ('Fred', 'Angela'), ('Alison', 'Angela'), ('Beatrice', 'Alison'), ('Dick', 'Alison'), ('Harry', 'Alison')]`

So what remains is to parse the name of the children in `mother child`, and see if child is a key in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get the following error though

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\untitled-1.py", line 18, in <module>
Syntax Error: print rel: C:\Users\user\Documents\untitled-1.py, line 189

Comment: @user2383844 Something got cut out from the paste. Anyway it should've been easy enough to fix for yourself. I urge you to actually learn some Python before you try to do something like this :) I can recommend [Codeacademy's Python course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python).

Comment: thanks for your help. I have actually figured out the whole thing today, but thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @user2383844 If you got it figured out you should [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).